# Integer solutions for $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all triples $(x, y, z)$ where $x, y, z$ are coprime integers such that $$\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}=\dfrac{1}{z^2}$$

I did the following:

$$\begin{split}\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}=\dfrac{1}{z^2} &\Rightarrow \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=z^2 \\ & \Rightarrow x^2y^2-x^2z^2-y^2z^2=0 \\ & \Rightarrow x^2y^2-x^2z^2-y^2z^2+z^4=z^4 \\ & \Rightarrow (z^2-x^2)(z^2-y^2)=z^4 \\ & \Rightarrow (x+z)(x-z)(y+z)(y-z)=z^4\end{split}$$

How should I go on?

Comment: For an answer see [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-x-2-+-y-2-z-2).

Comment: Your equations are not wrong, but they are a little misleading: we know $z^2 < x^2$ and $z^2 < y^2$, so $(x^2-z^2)(y^2-z^2)$ is more natural than $(z^2-x^2)(z^2-y^2)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: this answer is quite partial.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Just coprime or pairwise coprime? Because $15,20,12$ are coprime...

Comment: It's $gcd(x_0, y_0, z_0) = 1 $. I think there are 3 satisfying pairs including $(15, 20, 12)$. But I want to check if the factorization is helpful...

Comment: @SubhadeepDey yes, $x,y,z$ are coprime integers.

Comment: It's easier, I think, to multiply with $x^2y^2$, set $w = \frac{xy}{z}$ - which must be an integer, since it's a rational number whose square is an integer, and then use the parametrisation of Pythagorean triples. $w$ must divide $\bigl(\gcd(x,y)\bigr)^2$, and $\gcd\bigl(x,y,\frac{xy}{w}\bigr) = 1$ then determines $\gcd(x,y)$ in terms of the parametrisation. That gives you a parametrisation of the (infinitely many) coprime solutions.

Comment: you mean that $\Big(x, y, \frac{xy}{w}\Big) = \Big((m^2-n^2), (2mn), (m^2+n^2)\Big)$ ?

Comment: Not quite, it's $\bigl((m^2-n^2)(m^2+n^2), 2mn(m^2+n^2), 2mn(m^2-n^2)\bigr)$.

Comment: How so? I thought that all the pythagorean triplets are given by $\Big(k(m^2+n^2), 2kmn, k(m^2+n^2)\Big)$ and we get all the primitive triplets for $k=1$

Comment: Yes, but that parametrisation gives us $(x,y,w)$ [apart from a typo, you wrote $m^2+n^2$ twice, the first should be $m^2 - n^2$]. We want $w \mid xy$, so that $z = \frac{xy}{w}$ is an integer. That gives us $(m^2+n^2) \mid k(m^2-n^2)2mn$. Since $m,n$ are coprime and of opposite parity, that only holds if $(m^2+n^2) \mid k$. And we find that $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$ only if $k = m^2+n^2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, oh, I thought pairwise coprime.

Answer (score 6):

For the equation.

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}$$

Use a Pythagorean triple.

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Obtained solutions.

$$x=ac$$

$$y=bc$$

$$z=ab$$

Comment: If the OP meant $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$, then this is a good, short answer.

Comment: If not, the answer is still short and good (+1). It seems to be a good idea to suppose that $gcd(x,y,z)=1$.

Comment: Nice answer. +1